# Different persistence repositories for an aggregate in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I have an aggregate with a root entity (Documentation) and a VO (Document). Documents are associated with files (pdfs, images, office documents, etc), so I have to persist the aggregate in a database and files in a ftp server (files cannot be saved in the database because space files is too large).
My db repository class implements an interface with methods like FindXXX, AddDocument, RemoveDocument and others. How could I implement ftp persistence? Should my db repository connect to ftp setver in AddDocument and RemoveDocument? Or I should create a ftp repository class that implements the interface. If so, methods like FindXXX not make sense.
As far as I know about DDD, each aggregate have only one interface repository that represents how can be persisted. It can have multiple "persistence modes" (in a db, ftp, file, etc) but the interface should the same.

Answer (score 5):

> As far as I know about DDD, each aggregate have only one interface repository that represents how can be persisted.

That's mostly true; people generally assume that an entire aggregate is going to be stored in a single place.  When you distribute the state of the aggregate across multiple storage units, your failure modes need very careful attention.

So one thing to consider is whether the separately stored documents are something that are *part* of the aggregate, or something that is *referenced by* the aggregate.

If they are *referenced by* the aggregate, then you treat them like any other reference to another aggregate.  The documentation aggregate stores a identifier/reference/hint for the document, and takes advantage of a domain service to access the document if it needs it.

If they are *part of* the aggregate, then the usual answer is that "the repository" will be a facade in front of a complicated infrastructure thing that masks the fact that the documentation and the document(s) are stored separately.

In other words, the infrastructure layer will be trying to orchestrate the load and store operations, and the rest of the system doesn't need to know the details.

Comment: Mmm.. interesting question. And I'm not sure. Partially it's part of the aggregate because the file (Document VO class) is part of the Documentation entity. But, on the other hand, when I execute FindXXX method in repository, I don't load all documents in ftp site, I only load db information. I'm not sure what is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Late response. But, simply put, you should have two services. In my reading of DDD, repositories are often considered as infrastructure services. In this case, you have two:

1. A repository / interface for storage, and basic retrieval of document IDs, metadata, and references
2. A repository / interface for storage, and basic retrieval of blobs of data

Sometimes it makes sense to have multiple aggregates, and repositories. In fact, some of Vaughn Vernon examples on bounded contexts (https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples) do include aggregates holding references to other aggregates. I would argue that you should do what makes sense, and what feels appropriate.

Indeed, if you were running a post office collection centre, chances are you will have a way of 1. storing the small to large parcels, and 2. curating an index of where every small to large parcels are located in the centre so that you can retrieve it.

> My db repository class implements an interface with methods like FindXXX, AddDocument, RemoveDocument and others. How could I implement ftp persistence? Should my db repository connect to ftp setver in AddDocument and RemoveDocument? Or I should create a ftp repository class that implements the interface.

If your database repository connects to FTP in addition to some other data store, you may arguably be putting too much logic, and responsibility in one area. That said, there is nothing wrong with doing this too.

> If so, methods like FindXXX not make sense. As far as I know about DDD, each aggregate have only one interface repository that represents how can be persisted.

For this specific problem, most DDD practitioners will recommend you have a separate view service / model. It can produce a materialised / view DTO across repositories or services.

Fundamentally, it should be easy to test individual parts, and to replace underlying implementations. If you decided to switch (or even include support) from FTP to Google Cloud Storage / AWS S3 one day, then there might be more work involved, and changes to test cases.