# Is it okay to have more than one repository for an aggregate in DDD?

Tags: repository, domain-driven-design, persistence, datamapper, ddd-repositories

I've read [this question about something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48581756/different-persistence-repositories-for-an-aggregate-in-ddd) but it didn't quite solve my problem.

I have an application where I'm required to use data from an API. Problem is there are performance and technical limitations to doing this. The performance limitations are obvious. The technical limitations lie in the fact that the API does not support some of the more granular queries I need to make.

I decided to use MySQL as a queryable cache.

Since the data I needed to retrieve from the API did not change very often, I settled on refreshing the cache once a day, so I didn't need any complicated mapper that checked if we had the data in the cache and if not fell back to the API. That was my first design, but I realized that wasn't very practical when the API couldn't support most of the queries I needed to make anyway.

Now I have a set of two mappers for every aggregate. One for MySQL and one for the API.

My problem is now how I hide the complexities of persistence from the domain, and the fact that it seems that I need multiple repositories.

Ideally I would have an interface that both mappers adhered to, but as previously disclosed that's not possible.

Is it okay to have multiple repositories, one for each mapper?

Comment: This seems like a good time to do a little [Context Mapping](https://www.infoq.com/articles/ddd-contextmapping). Right now you're considering your application and the external API to be in the same Bounded Context, which is kind of odd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it okay to have more than one repository for an aggregate in DDD?

Short answer: yes.

Longer answer: you won't find any suggestion of multiple repository in the original book by Evans.  As he described things, the domain model would have one representation of *the* aggregate, and the repository abstraction provided consumers with the illusion that the aggregate was stored in an in-memory collection.

Largely, this makes sense -- you are trying to ensure that writes to data within the aggregate boundary are consistent, so you need a single authority for change.

But... there's no particular reason that reads need to travel through the same code path as writes.  Welcome to the world of [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs).  What that gives you immediately is the idea that the in memory representation for reads might need to be optimized differently from the in memory representation used for writes.

In its more general form, you get the idea that the concept that you are modeling might have different representations for each use case.

For your case, where it is sometimes appropriate to read from the RDBMS, sometimes from the API, sometimes both, this isn't quite an exact match -- the repository interface hides the implementation details from the consumer, but you still have to bother with the implementation.

One thing you might look at is your requirements; how fresh does the data need to be in each use case?  A constraint that is often relaxed in the CQRS pattern is the idea that the effects of writes are immediately available for reading.  The important question to ask would be, if the data hasn't been cached yet, can you simply report "data not available" without hitting the API?

If so, then use cases that access the cached data need only a single repository implementation.

Comment: I'm actually already using CQRS in another place in my application for a different reason. The reason I wanted to still use two repositories is that I can still have a single source of truth for each persistence mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using external API to read and modify data, you can cache them locally to be faster in reads, but I would avoid to have a **domain repository**.

From the domain perspective it seems that you need a service to query (or just a Query in CQRS implementation) for some data, that you can do with a service, that internally can call some remote API or read from a local cache (mysql, whatever).
When you read your local cache you can develop a repository to decouple your logic from the db implementation, but this is a different concept from a **domain repository**, it is just a detail of your technical implementation, that has nothing to do with your domain.
If the remote service start offering the query you need you will change the implementation of *how* your query is executed, calling the remote API instead of the db, but your domain model should not change.

A domain repository is used to load and persist **your** aggregates, meanwhile if you are working with external aggregates (in a different context, subdomain) you need to interact with them using services.